# USB devices don't work without system reboot - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, usb, lsusb

Whenever I plug in a USB device to my laptop while it is still running, it does not work. However, when I plug in a USB device while the laptop is off and boot with it in the USB slot, the device works perfectly fine, but stops working if it is taken out and put back in again.

It appears to show up in $ lsusb (while not working):

**Without device:**

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0c45:6421 Microdia 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 138a:0008 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS300 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 413c:8160 Dell Computer Corp. Wireless 365 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 413c:8162 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Touchpad [Synaptics]
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 413c:8161 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**With device:**

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0c45:6421 Microdia 
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 138a:0008 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS300 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 413c:8160 Dell Computer Corp. Wireless 365 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 413c:8162 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Touchpad [Synaptics]
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 413c:8161 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**sudo journalctl -f results:**

```
Feb 08 04:02:50 ziptol-Vostro-3500 upowerd[6709]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.2/1-1.1.2:1.0
Feb 08 04:02:50 ziptol-Vostro-3500 upowerd[6709]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.2/1-1.1.2:1.0
Feb 08 04:02:50 ziptol-Vostro-3500 upowerd[6709]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.2/1-1.1.2:1.0
Feb 08 04:02:50 ziptol-Vostro-3500 kernel: usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52b, bcdDevice=12.03
Feb 08 04:02:50 ziptol-Vostro-3500 kernel: usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Feb 08 04:02:50 ziptol-Vostro-3500 kernel: usb 2-1.1: Product: USB Receiver
Feb 08 04:02:50 ziptol-Vostro-3500 kernel: usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: Logitech
Feb 08 04:02:50 ziptol-Vostro-3500 upowerd[6709]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.2/1-1.1.2:1.0
Feb 08 04:02:50 ziptol-Vostro-3500 kernel: logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C52B.0015: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1/input2
Feb 08 04:02:50 ziptol-Vostro-3500 upowerd[6709]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.2/1-1.1.2:1.0
Feb 08 04:02:50 ziptol-Vostro-3500 upowerd[6709]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.2/1-1.1.2:1.0
Feb 08 04:02:50 ziptol-Vostro-3500 upowerd[6709]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.2/1-1.1.2:1.0
```

This is the data that I got when I plugged in a Logitech USB Wireless mouse. The rest of the data before and after plugging in is filled with the "unhandled action 'bind', unhandled action 'unbind'" outputs.

All of my USB ports are USB 2.0.

**Laptop Specs:**
    DELL Vostro 3500 - Bios Version: A09

I'm still quite new to Linux, so excuse any lapses in the data I've provided here. Any further troubleshooting advice and suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: For testing purposes only, download an Ubuntu alternative 'flavour' with a different Desktop Environment, from https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours . The ISO file you use to create a LiveUSB should be checked for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 . Make a LiveUSB following these instructions on another Linux PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0 or on a Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0 .

Comment: Watch `sudo journalctl -f` as you plug in your device.

Comment: I have a similar issue, but only with an aftermarket USB 3 card I installed. The built-in USB 2 ports work fine. Are your affected  ports USB 3?

Comment: waltinator and Organic Marble I've edited my post to address your questions.